# How to parse the json data using swiftJson along with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

my Json data sample. this is only a sample of data .Likewise so much data available like number of subcategory is 22. number of items are different according to subcategory.Also number of rows are 15 in which the first name is Pizza.

```
[
 {
  "id": "244",
  "name": "PIZZAS",
  "image": "",
  "coupon": "1",
  "icon": "",
  "order": "1",
  "aname": "",
  "options": "2",
  "subcategory": [
              {
                "id": "515",
                "name": "MARGARITA",
                "description": "Cheese and Tomato",
                "image": "",
                "icon": "",
                "coupon": "1",
                "order": "1",
                "aname": "",
                "options": "2",
                "item": [
                            {
                               "id": "1749",
                               "name": "9 Inch Thin & Crispy Margarita",
                               "description": "",
                               "price": "3.40",
                               "coupon": "1",
                               "image": "",
                               "options": "2",
                               "order": "1",
                               "addon": "495",
                               "aname": "",
                               "icon": ""
                        }]
          }]
  }]
```

[image] [image]

I want to fetch the all name, all subcategory name, all item name and all item description into particular array so that i can populate particularly into different tableview

```
func ParseJSON(){
     var MenuList = [Menu]()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                     print("JSON: \(json)")
                      for entity in json{
                        print(entity)
                       MenuList.append(entity["name"])  ///error
                    }

                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }

}
```

I am able to fetch the response using Alamofire. Now How to implement it using swiftJson ??

**Updated**

I have added the class model for main category, subcategory and items.

```
    import UIKit
    class Menu {
                 var id: Int?
                 var name: String?
                 var image: UIImage?
                 var coupon: Int?
                 var icon: UIImage?
                 var order: Int?
                 var aname: Int?
                 var options: Int?

init(id:Int,name:String,image:UIImage,coupon:Int,icon:UIImage,order:Int,aname:Int,options:Int){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.coupon = coupon
        self.icon = icon
        self.order = order
        self.aname = aname
        self.options = options


    }
   }
```

how to pass the data to the class  and get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `json` is already a SwiftyJSON object.

These objects always have an index key and a content key.

So to loop over the json you need `for (_, entity) in json` instead of `for entity in json`.

*The `_` part is the index that we ignore. We could also do `for (index, entity) in json` if we wanted to use the index.*

You also need to use SwiftyJSON's type properties, like `.string` (optional) or `.stringValue` (non optional).

In your model class, the properties types have to reflect the ones you get.

To populate an array of `Menu` objects from the first level of your JSON, you could adapt your model like this:

```
class Menu {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var image: String?
    var coupon: Int?
    var icon: String?
    var order: Int?
    var aname: String?
    var options: Int?

    init(id: Int?, name: String?, image: String?, coupon: Int?, icon: String?, order: Int?, aname: String?, options: Int?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.coupon = coupon
        self.icon = icon
        self.order = order
        self.aname = aname
        self.options = options
    }
}
```

Then populate an array from the JSON:

```
var menus = [Menu]()

for (_, content) in json {
    let menu = Menu(id: Int(content["id"].stringValue),
                    name: content["name"].string,
                    image: content["image"].string,
                    coupon: content["coupon"].int,
                    icon: content["icon"].string,
                    order: Int(content["order"].stringValue),
                    aname: content["name"].string,
                    options: Int(content["options"].stringValue))
    menus.append(menu)
}
```

Now you can iterate over your objects as you need:

```
for menu in menus {
    print(menu.name)
    print(menu.id)
}
```

Prints:

> Optional("PIZZAS")
>   Optional(244)

Now if you want to also use the data in the "subcategory" of each object, you have to make other model classes which reflect these properties, like a "SubCategory" class and an "Item" class (those could be also stored in each Menu, for example). And you use the same system as my example to populate them - you just have to adapt to each format, but now that you have this working example it should be rather simple to get there. The trick is to understand your JSON structure well enough so that you can reflect it in your model objects. Focus primarily on this and the rest will follow. :)

Comment: In the image section while populating an array , i think there instead of .string  , .image have to use. because there it gives error like can't convert value of string to UIimage

Comment: You can't have images in JSON. In your example JSON, we see `"image": ""`, the content is a String. This String (which is empty in your example) is probably the URL that you can use to get your image after having parsed the JSON.

Comment: Now i got it. i have taken it as UIImage in modal class

Comment: Cool! Notice that I've closed your other question because it was the same as this one. Once you have solved decoding your JSON in this one, you can ask a new one if you need, focused on the tableView part. I hope I didn't confuse you with this. Thanks! :)

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. I hope you'll find the answers you need.

Comment: but i have one question in my mind Eric. if i need to fetch the image and have to show it. then its confusing me  bacon i have taken image as string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115821/discussion-between-eric-d-and-pradip-kumar).